# How does `Currency::pair(burn)` work?

Tags: balances

```rust
if !missed_any {
    // burn some proportion of the remaining budget if we run a surplus.
    let burn = (T::Burn::get() * budget_remaining).min(budget_remaining);
    budget_remaining -= burn;

    let (debit, credit) = T::Currency::pair(burn);
    imbalance.subsume(debit);
    T::BurnDestination::on_unbalanced(credit);
    Self::deposit_event(Event::Burnt { burnt_funds: burn })
}
```

Upper code is taken from [treasury](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L592) pallet. I checked the balances pallet, but can not find the `pair` call. Can anyone explain how this `pair` call works? I'll be appreciated if anyone can point out the source of this function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the treasury pallet the Currency trait is imported from the [frame support pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/support) (see import [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L75)).

If you go to the source code of the FRAME support pallet, you can check the  [Currency](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/currency.rs#L97) trait and associated types, and the pair():

```rs
    /// Produce a pair of imbalances that cancel each other out exactly.
    ///
    /// This is just the same as burning and issuing the same amount and has no effect on the
    /// total issuance.
    fn pair(amount: Self::Balance) -> (Self::PositiveImbalance, Self::NegativeImbalance) {
        (Self::burn(amount), Self::issue(amount))
    }
```